# How to style dynamically added nested elements in react

Tags: css, reactjs

I was dynamically adding nested categories and subacatogories in react. I want to hide and show the sub-categories on clicking or hovering main-category. I wanted to show/hide subcatogories(mobiles, tv, laptops) on clicking Accessories and wanna show/hide Noodles on clicking groceries. Please help

My Code:

```js
import React from "react";

function App(props) {
  const categoriesList = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "Accessories",
      slug: "accessories",
      children: [
        {
          id: "2",
          name: "Mobiles",
          slug: "mobiles",
        },
        {
          id: "3",
          name: "TV",
          slug: "tv",
        },
        {
          id: "4",
          name: "Laptops",
          slug: "laptops",
          children: [
            {
              id: 5,
              name: "Dell",
              slug: "dell",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: "6",
      name: "Books",
      slug: "books",
      // children: undefined,
    },
    {
      id: "7",
      name: "Groceries",
      slug: "groceries",
      children: [
        {
          id: "8",
          name: "Noodles",
          slug: "noodles",
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  const renderCategories = (categories) => {
    let myCategories = [];

    for (const category of categories) {
      myCategories.push(
        <li className="category-list" key={category.name}>
          {category.name}
          {category?.children?.length > 0 ? (
            <ul className="nested-category">
              {renderCategories(category.children)}
            </ul>
          ) : null}
        </li>
      );
    }

    return myCategories;
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <ul className="main">{renderCategories(categoriesList)}</ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: https://naisutech.github.io/react-tree/?path=/story/naisutech-react-tree--basic
Is this what you want? If it is, I can provide a quick implementation

Answer (score 0):

You need a state like `categoryToBeDisplayed` and then just have an onClick on the category `li` tag

```
for (const category of categories) {
  myCategories.push(
    <li className="category-list" key={category.name} onClick={() => setCategory(category.name)}>
      {category.name}
      {category?.children?.length > 0 && categoryToBeDisplayed === category.name ? (
        <ul className="nested-category">
          {renderCategories(category.children)}
        </ul>
      ) : null}
    </li>
  );
}
```

And if you want multiple to be open at once just have the state accept an array and check if `categoryToBeDisplayed.includes(category.name)`